# Are cognitive maps still widely studied within psychology? Why or why not?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, cognitive-modeling

[Cognitive maps](http://psc.dss.ucdavis.edu/sommerb/sommerdemo/mapping/cogmap.htm) refer to mental representations of physical spaces. It seems like the work on this concept dropped off significantly in the 1990s but I’m not in the field, so I can’t say for sure. Are they still relevant for use in studies in psychology?

Comment: Could you explain what a cognitive map is and why you are interested? That may help people answering your question.

Comment: Added definition of cognitive maps. Thanks

Comment: [Here](http://www.icn.ucl.ac.uk/nburgess/papers/BurgessOKeefe2011.pdf) is a neuroscientific paper from 2011 that discusses the function of "place cells" and "grid cells" in the brain. It seems thus that cognitive maps still exist. It is rather (read, extremely) technical, however, but it may be a nice place to start.